# Sticky-able Questions on Meta

Tags: feature-request, questions

Perhaps the SO Team could make certain questions float to the top of the stack for set periods of time? For instance, to get suggestions for an upcoming dev-day, or and upcoming podcast episode. **The ability to sticky would be solely in the hands of admins**.

**Note**: The types of questions stickied would be few and far in between. It's just an easier way for the admins to keep a topic in the forefront.

Comment: Why not use phpBB to begin with?

Comment: I'm referring to the exception, not the rule. SO and phpBB are apples and oranges, merging in the part that topics sometimes need to be amplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they could better implement this just by having one of their "messages" that appears on the pages near the top alerting you to the question and then provide a link. They could then leave that up for however much time was desired, and it would be a lot easier to implement than trying to wildly modify the way questions are aggregated.

Comment: That would work too. +1

Comment: The problem with the bar on the top is that it's designed mainly for announcements. I wouldn't feel comfortable linking to random questions from it.

Comment: Kyle: I was hoping that the only questions that got linked would be announcements of some sort (like an announcement of Jeff looking for input on a certain feature implementation). I definitely would not want to see anything like "Hey this question is pretty good, let's stick it to the top for everyone to see"

Comment: @TheTXI: Ok, that makes sense. Though I'm *pretty sure* that the question originally said "moderators" instead of "admins".

Comment: Kyle: I have no idea if it did or not. I just assumed Admins because I couldn't imagine giving the power to someone like myself.

Comment: +1 & I'll delete my answer

Comment: @Kyle, I was having the same issue about the change, it *did* say moderators. I disagreed for this reason, but it seems to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd disagree on the need for this. That's what the SO blog is for.

Comment: Meta is more a dialogue than the blog is.

Answer (score 0):

A post on SO about suggestions for a dev-day or a podcast would (and should) immediately be closed as not programming related. If those things need promotion on SO, the guys can buy ad space from themselves (as, in case of the dev days, they actually did).

Edit: I just now noticed you're talking about meta.SO. Your point is more valid here than on SO; however, I still disagree that this would be a good feature.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Read my question-title. "...on Meta."

Comment: Yep, sorry, just noticed and edited.

Comment: I've removed my down-vote. Could you please tell me why you think it would be a bad idea to enable focused-dialogue for special instances?

Comment: Because meta still is the uservoice replacement. It's there for the technical (in the broader sense) discussion of the usage of the SO family. In my opinion, "What's going to be at the dev-days" kind of questions don't belong here either. My downvote for your request means a totally different thing here than a downvote on SO would (although I know the tooltips are the same as on SO). It does not mean I don't see your point or that you're unclear , but that I don't think the requested feature is useful.

Comment: To clarify: For the most part, I see meta as a voting-enabled feature request tracker with some side-discussion.

Answer (score -1):

A good example of this is on the stackexchange site: [List of StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites). A tab for read-me-first or similar would be good. It depends how lazy people are with searching